# Set JAVA_HOME on Mac

Tags: java, macos

I´ve tried everything but can´t set JAVA_HOME on a mac. Some say´s all you got to do is `echo export "JAVA_HOME=\$(/usr/libexec/java_home)" >> ~/.bash_profile`

I did, and restarted my shell and this is what it shows up:

```
-bash: /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home: is a directory
```

This ALWAYS shows up no matter which method of setting the variable I´ve used. 
My jdk 7 that I want to use is in my Library but the 1.6 that´s being used now is in System folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have two versions of Java installed - 1.6 and 1.7 on my mac. Depend upon which version I would like to use, I just change the entry in `.bash_profile` file.

Below is my `.bash_profile` looks like for version 1.6

```
cat .bash_profile

export JAVA_HOME='$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.6)'
```

Comment: Be aware that this won't be visible in applications launched from the dock. You might want something like https://github.com/hschmidt/EnvPane for that.

Comment: atamanroman: I downloaded that software and made a variable named JAVA_HOME and set the path to the home folder of my jdk. Is that all I need to do?